# Distinguish between transparency and extra alpha channels?

Tags: transparency, tiff, alpha-transparency, cmyk, exiftool

I am sorry in advance if I am not explaining my question really well. I am not 100% aware of the stuff I am asking.

Lets say that I have some CMYK tiff files. Is there a way that I can distinguish the difference between transparency and extra alpha channel ?

I used exiftools in the terminal with the command : exiftool -G -S filename.tif and I got a tag (ExtraSamples) that provides information about the alpha channel. Is there a way that I can distinguish the aforementioned difference ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? If not, please comment and/or re-phrase your question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [ExtraSamples](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/extrasamples.html) TIFF tag description. According to the specification, the tag can have one of three values (per sample above the "natural" number of samples for the color model, i.e. 1 for gray, 3 for RGB or 4 for CMYK):

> 0 = Unspecified data
>
> 1 = Associated alpha data (with pre-multiplied color)
>
> 2 = Unassociated alpha data

Now, what you mean by *"the difference between transparency and extra alpha channel"* isn't really clear to me, as I often use the terms "transparency" and "alpha channel" interchangeably. Perhaps you just mean the above (1 "associated" vs 2 "unassociated" alpha).

Any other extra samples, will use 0 ("unspecified"). Note that these extra samples are *not* used for transparency or alpha information. However, their meaning is application specific, and would require further context to properly interpret. So if your file contains unspecified `ExtraSamples`, this is most likely not alpha channels or transparency at all.

The link in your comment makes it somewhat more clear what you refer to by *"the difference between transparency and extra alpha channel"*. However, the link talks about the difference between an **alpha channel** and **a (bit) mask**, which are just two types of **transparency**.

`ExtraSamples` in a TIFF is typically not used for bit masks, instead a separate IFD with `SubFileType` "mask" (`4`) is used.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not really clear on enough, I am not 100% aware of these subjects.

I think that, transparency and alpha channels are two different meanings that have almost the same (similar) result. Not sure if that is the case. I read that resource: http://www.geniusdv.com/news_and_tutorials/2008/08/alpha_channels_and_transparency_3_back_to_the_basi.php

I ve checked the tag description and found ExtraSamples: Unknown (0,0. Which means, two unspecified alpha channels, right ?

BTW, thanks for your reply !

Comment: Thanks for your help !