# exiftool returns Unknown (1 0) as Extra Samples values for an tif image

Tags: transparency, tiff, alpha, exiftool

I am using exiftool to find out if an tif image has any alpha property(to check transparency).
The command I am using is like
`exiftool -ExtraSamples -T abcd.tif`

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892985/distinguish-between-transparency-and-extra-alpha-channels) link I understood the concept of checking alpha

I have normally seen exiftool return 'Associated Alpha' or 'Unassociated Alpha' as Extra Samples value

But for one particular file Extra Samples value returns 'Unknown (1 0)'
Can anyone please explain what does this mean?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the file (or knowning `exiftool` in more depth), but I would guess that your TIFF file has two `ExtraSamples` values (i.e. two extra channels), one 1 ("Associated") and one 0 ("Unspecified"). Does that make sense? What does other tags, like `BitsPerSample` or `SamplesPerPixel` and `PhotometricInterpretation` say?

Comment: Ah, Ok, understood. Thanks.
Here are the values you asked - 
Bits Per Sample : 8 8 8 8 8,
Photometric Interpretation : RGB,
Samples Per Pixel : 5,

Comment: Does this mean if one of the value in Unknown (x, y) is 1 or 2, the the image have alpha channel data?

Comment: If I'm correct, yes. In your sample file, there are 5 channels, in the order R, G, B, A, X (RGB given by the `PhotometricInterpretation` tag and AX by the `ExtraSamples` tag). What X is, is undefined. But there's an alpha/transparency channel there.